# Plotting a step (piecewise) function with vertical lines

Tags: matlab, plot, piecewise

Trying to plot a signal function of 0 and 1, much like the solution given to the question below:
[How to plot non-numeric data in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715535/how-to-plot-non-numeric-data-in-matplotlib)

However, I'd like to have vertical lines instead of bent ones when the function goes from 0 to 1. So for instance if f(x)=0 for x = 1 2 3 4 and f(x) = 1 thereafter, I'd like a horizontal line at y=0 up to x=5, and a vertical line at x=5 going from y=0 to y=1, and then a horizontal line at y=1 thereafter

Can this be done within the plot function? Or do I need to draw a ton of squares?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [stairs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/stairs.html) function?

Comment: I actually had a matplotlib question - not sure why matlab came as a keyword. But you still put me in the right direction as I looked for the matplotlib equivalent of 'stairs'.
The solution is drawstyle='steps' in the plot argument

Comment: @user1045479: check this out: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=27036226

Answer (score 4):

You can use [stairs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/stairs.html) or [area](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/area.html) functions. As shown [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/12026-area-stairs):

```
%# Sample input
x = 1:10;
y = [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1];

subplot(2,1,1)
stairs(x,y)
title('Stairs chart (non area)')

subplot(2,1,2)
x = [x;x];
y = [y;y];
area(x([2:end end]),y(1:end))
title('Stairs area')
```

[image: Stairs with area]